# ¿Cómo añadir un valor en una lista dentro de otra lista que ya existe? C#

Tags: c#

tengo un fallo y no se como arreglar el fallo es el siguiente:
Tengo una lista, que a su vez es de tipo <List<String>>, con el constructor lo que hago es guardar cierta info, y lo que tengo codificado es lo siguiente:

```
    List<List<string>> opciones = new List<List<string>>();
public Opcion(){
    var opcionesC = File.ReadAllText(this.dir).Split(";R;").ToList();
    opcionesC.RemoveAll(item => item == "");
    for(int i=0;i<opcionesC.Count;i++){
        this.opciones.Add(new List<string>());
        string[] opc= opcionesC[i].Split("\n");
        foreach(var t in opc){
            if(t.IndexOf(";Marc;")!=-1){
                this.opciones[i].Add(t);//Solo se añade este de aqui.
            }
            if(t.IndexOf(";Model;")!=-1){
                this.opciones[i].Add(t.Remove(0,5));//El problema es esto, no se quiere añadir.
            }
            if(t.IndexOf(";Tip;")!=-1){
                this.opciones[i].Add(t.Remove(0,3)); //El problema es esto, no se quiere añadir.
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Luego al hacer un output me sale lo siguiente;

```
Marca: Audi
Marca: BMW
```

etc..
Y lo que necesito es que me salga lo siguiente:

```
Marca: Audi
Modelo: A4
Tipo: Turismo
```

Ejemplo de archivo:

```
;Marca; Adui
;Modl; A4
;Tip; Turismo
;Marca; BMW
;Modl; S3
;Tip; Turismo
```

Alguien sabría decirme donde esta el fallo, Gracias!

Comment: pero... mas alla de que C no tenia nada que hacer aca... que es t? como sabemos si el problema es lo que viene en t u otra cosa?

Comment: Y ademas.. deberiamos ver como sacas ese output...

Comment: @gbianchi la T es el contenido que quiero guardar en mi lista, la que des de un fichero txt lo que hago es buscar ciertas claves para sacar la marca el modelo y el tipo.Per el add no quiere añadir el mi lista

Comment: Y como viene tu archivo?

Comment: @gbianchi tipo esto 
Tip     XXX
Model XXX
Marca XXX
Son ejemplos, el dato se recoge de forma correcta solo que el add no lo guarda en la lista

Comment: Podrias agregar a tu pregunta un ejemplo de tu archivo? porque por lo que veo, primero lo separas por algo, y luego como si viniera en distintas filas? no parece ser como viene tu archivo...

Comment: @gbianchi De es forma es mi archivo

Comment: Perfecto? hiciste un debug? porque el primer split no divide nada... el otro si... pero en cada opt queda una fila distinta....

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119164/discussion-between-moha-mbs-and-gbianchi).

Comment: @gbianchi Si aqui lo puedes ver https://tmpsee.com/co1wumshs

Comment: A tu lista : `List<List<string>> opciones = new List<List<string>>()`, quieres agregar cada una de las opciones del archivo text.txt ?

Comment: El código no coincide con lo del archivo: Marc -> Marca, Model -> Modl